# web3.js getGasPrice retuns null

Tags: web3js, metamask

I replace my MetaMask's web3 with web3.js 1.0.0-beta.34, and getGasPrice always returns null under *every* network --

```
window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
console.log('web3.version = ' + web3.version);
web3.eth.getGasPrice(gasPrice => {
    console.log('gasPrice = ' + gasPrice);
});
```

i.e., from mainnet to Ropsten to my private network ( ganache-cli ) log --

```
web3.version = 1.0.0-beta.34
gasPrice = null
```

Does anyone else have the same experience? What could have gone wrong?

Comment: To other users, here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/48837262/425648

Comment: @MaulikVora the link you proposed is following web3.js' 0.2 API, the web3 1.0 API can be found at https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getgasprice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the correct syntax for web3 **1.0** should be --

```
web3.eth.getGasPrice().then(gasPrice => {
   console.log('gasPrice = ' + gasPrice);
});
```

which logs --

```
gasPrice = 20000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Another **async** way:

```
  let transaction = await any_function;
  let gasUsed = transaction.receipt.gasUsed;
  let txInfo = await web3.eth.getTransaction(transaction.tx);
  let gasPrice = txInfo.gasPrice;
  console.log(gasPrice);
```

Comment: While it's good to learn about the gasPrice for a transaction, web3.eth.getGasPrice() returns the average gas price without having to have a transaction. The difference is subtle but important as getGasPrice() is commonly used to gauge the gas price _to be used_ for a future transaction